# fileManger returns Error I have no permission to view files in Package

Tags: swift, macos, file-manager

I' trying to get file names from directory. Now I have two ways to access that place: one by Open Panel where I can set directory by dragging files from opened by "Open Package Content" Finder window, manually select all files (end execute). And second – by iterating URLs. The second way doesn't work because of:

```
The file “glyphs” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it
```

I can view it from Finder, access from the same app by Open Panel... Hmm.
I create URL like this:

```
print ("filename <\(filename)>, \(isDirectory ? "Directory" : "File")")
let urlf = url.appendingPathComponent(filename, isDirectory: isDirectory)
print( "\(urlf.isFileURL ? "this is a file" : "not a file:") \(urlf)" )
```

Output from this code is:

```
filename <glyphs>, Directory
this is a file: file:///Users/lukasz/Documents/ClanTestDesignSpace/masters/ClnNew-BlackUltraExpandedHigh.ufo/glyphs/
```

URL is OK, I made "copy glyphs as pathname" in finder and compared both: they're exactly the same except last slash. But it's not Directory anymore `this is a file`.

Anyway I send this URL to:

```
let fileURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: urlf, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
```

Always returns Error.
I tried to change `includingPropertiesForKeys: [URLResourceKey.nameKey]` bot with no effect.

I checked sandbox (`User Selected File : read/write`). What I can check more?

Comment: Is your app sandboxed?

Comment: Sandbox is on for User Selected File and Downloads Folder: read/write. Everything else is off. From the same app I can read those files, but only if i get directory by OpenPanel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a sandboxed application, you cannot programatically access files in any directory. Once you enable `User Selected File : read/write` access in Sandbox settings, you can use an `NSOpenPanel`/`NSSavePanel` to let your user select the files they want to give access to, but without explicit user interaction you cannot access the `~/Documents` folder that you tried accessing.

Comment: Yes. OK. Thanks. Now I have some strange outputs: errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled} but I can see files.

Comment: @Łukasz you might not be correctly presenting the `NSOpen/SavePanel` and that might cause the error message, but I've only seen mentions of that specific error for `UIImagePickerController`, so it's weird

Comment: Hmm. I will investigate this.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?